# Соединить два массива php без методов

Tags: php, массивы

Я новичок в php. Вопрос, возможно, повторяющийся, но я подобного не нашёл. Бьюсь над этим уже несколько дней.
Как соединить два НЕ вложенных массива или больше, не используя методы (array_merge например)? Проблема в том, что значения с одинаковыми индексами перезаписываются, собственно это и есть самый большой камень преткновения. На js, например, с этим проблем вообще нет, а на php всю голову сломал уже.
Как соединить массивы без метода array_merge? Использовать метод - это слишком просто, а хотелось на примере кода разобраться, как можно слить два массива или лучше более (особенно перезапись ключей последующих массивов, сливаемых с первым и добавление количества аргументов по желанию, типа ...spread).

К сожалению, ничего лучше у меня не получилось, последующие массивы получаются вложенными. Знаю, что это бред, и знаю, в чём причина, но по другому делать тоже пробовал (foreach, array_map) - получается ещё бредовее.

```
$arr_first = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50];
    $arr_second = [15, 20, 25, 30, 35];
    $arr_third = [40, 45, 50, 55, 60];

    function conc($a, ...$args)
        {
            $res = [...$a, ...$args];
            return $res;
        }

    print_r(conc($arr_first, $arr_second, $arr_third));
```

Получается так:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 10
    [1] => 20
    [2] => 30
    [3] => 40
    [4] => 50
    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 15
            [1] => 20
            [2] => 25
            [3] => 30
            [4] => 35
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 40
            [1] => 45
            [2] => 50
            [3] => 55
            [4] => 60
        )

)
```

А надо так:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 10
    [1] => 20
    [2] => 30
    [3] => 40
    [4] => 50
    [5] => 15
    [6] => 20
    [7] => 25
    [8] => 30
    [9] => 35
    [10] => 40
    [11] => 45
    [12] => 50
    [13] => 55
    [14] => 60
)
```

Comment: чем цикл не устраивает?

Comment: Видимо пробовал не так как нужно было. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну вот два цикла:

```
$arr_first = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50];
$arr_second = [15, 20, 25, 30, 35];
$arr_third = [40, 45, 50, 55, 60];

function array_merge_custom(...$args) {
    $result = [];
    
    foreach ($args as $arr) {
        foreach ($arr as $item) {
            $result[] = $item;
        }
    }
    
    return $result;
}

print_r(array_merge_custom($arr_first, $arr_second, $arr_third));

// Output

Array
(
    [0] => 10
    [1] => 20
    [2] => 30
    [3] => 40
    [4] => 50
    [5] => 15
    [6] => 20
    [7] => 25
    [8] => 30
    [9] => 35
    [10] => 40
    [11] => 45
    [12] => 50
    [13] => 55
    [14] => 60
)
```

Comment: Круто, спасибо большое! То что нужно!

Comment: @AntAnt вот код в одну строку если хотите по разбираться(php 7.4+) если хотите использовать спред. Так же foreach заменен на reduce и делает то же самое что и в ответе. `$array_merge_custom = fn(...$args)  => array_reduce($args, fn($res, $arr) => [...$res, ...$arr], []);` print_r($array_merge_custom($arr_first, $arr_second, $arr_third));